# Japanese Imperial Calendar and Locale

Tags: java, servlets, calendar, locale

The ServeltRequest has a getLocale() method, the definition is:

```
Returns the preferred Locale that the client will accept content in, based on the Accept-Language header.
```

I wrote the following simple program:

```
 Locale loc = new Locale("ja", "JP", "JP");
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(loc);
 System.out.println(calendar.get(calendar.YEAR));
```

It successfully shows the Japanese Imperial Calendar instead of the GregorianCalendar.

Now, my question is: how can a user set up his browser e.g. Chrome so that `request.getLocale()` will return `Locale("ja", "JP", "JP")`? I tried to add the Japanese language but still I get the GregorianCalendar.

Comment: I'm not sure the calendar depends on the language part of the locale but rather on the country/region part. Did you try to set the browser to use `ja_JP` or even `ja_JP_JP`?

Comment: @Thomas I tried to change the country in Chrome but realised the only relevant thing I can change is the language. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure you can do that or how. As a workaround you could check the language and if it is Japanese provide country and variant yourself, i.e. convert `ja` to `ja_JP_JP`.

Answer (score 1):

From the source for `private static Calendar createCalendar(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale)` (the method that is called internally when you call `getCalendar(locale)`:

```
if (aLocale.hasExtensions()) {
        String caltype = aLocale.getUnicodeLocaleType("ca");
        if (caltype != null) {
            switch (caltype) {
            ...
            case "japanese":
                cal = new JapaneseImperialCalendar(zone, aLocale);
                break;
            ...
            }
        }
    }

if (cal == null) {
   ...     
   if (aLocale.getVariant() == "JP" && aLocale.getLanguage() == "ja"
                   && aLocale.getCountry() == "JP") {
            cal = new JapaneseImperialCalendar(zone, aLocale);
   } else {
            cal = new GregorianCalendar(zone, aLocale);
   }
}
```

As you can see in the second part, the locale needs to have country = JP, language = ja and variant = JP, i.e. a locale string of `ja_JP_JP`.

The problem is that browsers don't seem to directly support setting a country and variant in the language settings, so you might have to infer that yourself - depending on your needs:

- if the language is `ja` assume the country and the variant to both be `JP`
- use some form of geolocation to get the browser location and if the browser is in Japan set country and variant to `JP`
- let the user choose, i.e. start with just the language and let the user choose the type of calendar they want to use